# Laravel: How to use destroy with html forms

Tags: laravel-5

So since the form helpers arent included in laravel anymore. How do we call for a delete method with regular html forms? I can't find nothing about this, every example uses the form helpers..

thanks

Edit: It works using this:

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
```

However, a little bit of explanation would be nice.

Comment: Thank You!! Was looking for this